# Python For loop display previous value if correct one match with XML

Tags: python, xml

right now I have this [XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmkB2.png)

I need to get 1 value ("enabled") behind the correct one I get.

this is the code I'm using

```
def checktap(text):
  nodes = minidom.parse("file.xml").getElementsByTagName("node")
  for node in nodes:
      if node.getAttribute("text") == text:

          if node.getAttribute("enabled") == True:
              return ("Yes")
          else:
              return ("No")       


value = checktap("EU 39")
print(value)
```

with this code, I'll get the exact node I'm searching, and the value is enabled=True, but I need to get the one behind this (android.widget.LinearLayout) with the value enabled=False

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you mean by "behind"

Comment: Please post XML as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

```
from itertools import pairwise

def checktap(text):
    nodes = minidom.parse("file.xml").getElementsByTagName("node")
    for node1, node2 in pairwise(nodes):
        if node2.getAttribute("text") == text and node2.getAttribute("enabled"):
            return True
    return False
```